# ASP.NET MVC: No Data in Bar Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC binding Syncfusion Bar Chart in SQL Server however the data in the bar chart is not loading and there are no prompt error message in my code. I wonder what could be the problem. Here the output and my code.

ChartController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HMAC_PreFunding_QC_Checklist_WebAppln.Controllers.MainPage
{
    public class ChartController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Chart
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<ChartSqlData> data = new List<ChartSqlData>();
            string connectionString = null;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            //connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\LAPTOP-V3QJAMBF\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Incidents\EJ2\AspNetMvc5\CandleStick\AspNetMvc5\App_Data\NORTHWND.MDF;Integrated Security=True;";
            connectionString = @"Data Source=LAPTOP-V3QJAMBF\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HMAC_QC_PreFunding_DB;Integrated Security=True;";
            //connectionString = @"Data Source=LAPTOP-V3QJAMBF\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\HMAC Project\HMAC Pre-Funding QC Checklist\HMAC Pre-Funding QC Checklist\HMAC_PreFunding_QC_Checklist_WebAppln\bin\Debug\HMAC_QC_PreFunding_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;";
            //"Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;"
            //Data Source = LAPTOP-V3QJAMBF\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = D:\INCIDENTS\EJ2\ASPNETMVC5\CANDLESTICK\ASPNETMVC5\APP_DATA\NORTHWND.MDF; Integrated Security = True
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            string command2 = "SELECT * FROM [Summary_Of_Gross_QC_Loan_Audit_Finding] WHERE SumGr_QC_Loan_Risk < 1";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(command2, con);
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd1;
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string x1 = Convert.ToString(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SumGr_QC_Borrower_Name"]);
                int y1 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SumGr_QC_Loan_Risk"]);
                int y2 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SumGr_QC_Loan_Score"]);
                data.Add(new ChartSqlData(x1, y1, y2));
            }
            ViewBag.dataSource = data;
            return View();
        }
        [Serializable]
        public class ChartSqlData
        {
            public ChartSqlData(string xvalue, int yvalue1, int yvalue2)
            {
                this.SumGr_QC_Borrower_Name = xvalue;
                this.SumGr_QC_Loan_Risk = yvalue1;
                this.SumGr_QC_Loan_Score = yvalue2;
            }
            public string SumGr_QC_Borrower_Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public int SumGr_QC_Loan_Risk
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public int SumGr_QC_Loan_Score
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@*@{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }*@

@Html.EJS().Chart("container").Series(
    sr =>
    {
        sr.XName("SumGr_QC_Borrower_Name").YName("SumGr_QC_Loan_Risk").Name("Loan Risk").Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column).DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Add();
        sr.XName("SumGr_QC_Borrower_Name").YName("SumGr_QC_Loan_Score").Name("Loan Score").Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column).DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Add();
    }).PrimaryXAxis(
    xAxis =>
    {
        xAxis.ValueType(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ValueType.Category);

    }).ChartArea(area => area.Border(br => br.Color("transparent"))).Title("Pre-Funding Audit Report").Render()
<script>

</script>
```

The link below is the image output (no data display in my chart)
[Click me for the output image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K56AM.png)

[Console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN5F3.png)

[Network error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKReL.png)

Comment: Can you please check the console (Press F12) error and update

Comment: Yes I already posted

Comment: Did I really see SqlAdapter and DataSet being used in 2021?

Comment: Looks like a couple of requests fail, check network tab in dev tools for these failed requests.

Comment: What you you mean?

Comment: In both the console and network tab, there is a router.js file not found. so what is that and fix that path issue first and check.

Comment: I already solve it. Thank you!

Comment: Please post an answer detailing what you fixed and how. The question has no value without it and should otherwise be deleted.